# Getting a line from one implementation file to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have researched this and cant seem to find the right keywords to type in. But anyway I want to be able to use a line in my (1)header file and use it in (2)implementation file.

So for a rough example lets say I have two ViewController, one named labelViewController and the other named receiverViewController.

In the labelViewController.h file I would have something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface labelViewController : UIViewController {

    UILabel *label;

}

@end
```

Then I want to be able to use this label in a different view controller like this.

```
#import "ReceiverViewController.h"

@interface ReceiverViewController ()

@end

@implementation ReceiverViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label.text = @"Hello World";
}
```

How could I make this work?

---

### Edit

What would also work would be making a string in the receiveViewController and sending it to the labelViewController.

---

### Edit 2

What I am trying to do is set the title of a tableViewCell by the selection in a picker. I used a label to keep it more simple

Comment: Could you provide some additional context about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You shouldn't be directly changing properties (e.g. `text`) of one ViewController from another.  If `ReceiverViewController` should really be changing the label text, then `label` should probably be its own property and ivar.  [See here for more on Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: I suggest you review your design. It's usually not a good idea to try to save you from typing one line of code and messing up the whole architecture. If you think you'll use a label in most of your view controllers, then think about extracting that to a super class and making your view controllers inherit from that. But this still doesn't sound too realistic.

Comment: Im using a label as an example to keep it simple. Im really working on setting a title of a tableViewCell from a picker that is in another view.

Comment: Have the table view cell be configured from some model object. Have the table view reload when the model changes. Your picker delegate should also have a reference to the model and change its properties when rows are selected such that the table cell changes too.

Comment: Im really new to this erea of programming, so i dont follow you. Could you go into more detail in an answer? Ill update the question.

Comment: @user2660874 how do you decide what to put in the table cell's label now? Once you've identified that, then find a way to modify that state from the picker view, and have the table view be notified / observe that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have the @interface and @implementation have the same class name. Aside from that, it does not matter what file the @interface or @implementation is in as long as the @interface is accessable from the file the @implementation is in (in the same file or `#import`ed.

So in your case, if you did `@interface ReceiverViewController...` you would be fine.

Comment: Yes, Could you go into more detail? Not sure I did what you said

Comment: In the line `#import "ReceiverViewController.h"`, is the file you are importing the same one that has the @interface?

Comment: I think so, so far in my labelViewController has this added to it `#import "ReceiverViewController.h" @interface ReceiverViewController ()`

Comment: In your ReceiverViewController.h, do you declar `UILabel *label;`?

Comment: i think you misunderstood. The labelViewController has that declared

Comment: You cant declare something in one class and implement it in another. That is what I am trying to say. If you want to have your label in a labelViewController, you will either have to extend that class or create an instance of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35238/discussion-between-user2660874-and-jsdodgers)